# How do I make it take the floating route and not the main static route in this case?

Tags: routing, route, static

**In this topology I have configured the devices in this way:**

[image]

**R1:**

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 916 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2811/K9 sn FTX1017U862-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip address 10.1.1.5 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 172.16.3.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.2 
ip route 172.16.3.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.6 5
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 logging synchronous
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

**R2:**

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 714 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R2
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2811/K9 sn FTX101723IN-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.1.1.2 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.1.1.9 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 172.16.3.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.10 
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.1 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

**R3:**

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 715 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R3
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2811/K9 sn FTX1017BW6O-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.1.1.6 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.1.1.13 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 172.16.3.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.14 
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.5 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

**R4:**

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 889 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R4
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2811/K9 sn FTX1017OPU6-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.16.3.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.1.1.10 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip address 10.1.1.14 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.9 
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.13 5
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

***When I ping from PC1 to PC2, the path to go from PC1 to PC2 is as follows:***

[image]

**But the way back, to go from PC2 to PC1 is as follows: (causing the packet to be discarded)**

[image]

**Question:**

**How can I make the return route, that is, from PC2 to PC1, be as follows, that is, although the path through the upper static route is active, it goes through the lower floating static route?**

[image]

The packet tracer file is the following:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/3dvgy683vestflg/Static_Routes.pkt/file

Comment: We do not want the Packet Tracer file, but we need the network device configurations. Please edit your question to include all the router configurations.

Comment: Ok. I'll edit my question in a moment.

Comment: UPDATE: I've just edited my question...

Comment: Again, please edit the question to include the router configurations. Use the `show running-config` command, copy the text, paste it into the question, and use the Pre-formatted-Text feature (`{}`) that is right next to the image feature you used.

Comment: Stateful packet inspection cannot work with asymmetric routing. Either remove the one or fix the other.

Comment: UPDATE: I've just edited my question with all the configurations.

Comment: Could you also run a `show ip route` and add the output to your question? From the configs there's should be no asymmetric routing.

Answer (score 2):

R4 is sending it the wrong way to R2 SO you need to get router 4 to send it to R3
Theses are the two lines in R4 you need to fix

```
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.9 
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.13 5
```

Make the metric for R3 so it has a higher priority , lower metric - I tend to put metrics on all relevant routes so its obvious I thought about it  - replace the lines above with

```
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.9 10
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.13 5
```

Comment: I understand your solution, but what I want is that when the upper link between R1 and R2 is restored, the packets go up through R2, in the graph that I show on purpose, I take the link between R1 and R2 out of service to analyze the static route.
What I would like is that when the link between R1 and R2 goes down, the packets go through R3, but when the link between R1 and R2 goes up they go through R2.

Comment: That needs a routing protocol or assuming the routers support it SLA configuration, with SLA you can ping a device and then add a route if it succeeds

Comment: Also your question did not make it clear that you are changing the topology of the network "I take the link between R1 and R2 out of service ..."  This is pretty important to understand what you are trying to solve - it maybe the little red marks are to indicate that - but you need to make it clear